# log all powershell commands run on o365 tenant

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am wondering if there is a way to get a log of every powershell command ever run on our Office 365 server, and which user ran it? Can get the commands run in current powershell session but not historically...

advice is appreciated

Comment: I know nothing about Office 365 server, but on a normal server you would just enable a global PowerShell profile with `Start-Transcript ...` in it. A transcript file is then created for each PowerShell session.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the Administrator Audit Logs which records the use of the Exchange Cmdlets https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342832(v=exchg.150).aspx. The other way the covers Sharepoint as well is the new Activity API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference